# How to make some of jtextfield & jlabel not appear in JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I am currently making a GUI that prints a textarea. In this textarea I am required to receive the "weights" for the ID of the variable.

I have created multiple labels showing from ID1: - ID8: & their textfields, and use if statements instead but the with the amount of if and else if.

```
    if (id.size = 1){
    id1.setvisible(true);
    weight1TField.setvisible(true);
}else if (id.size = 2){
    id1.setvisible(true);
    weight1TField.setvisible(true);
    id2.setvisible(true);
    weight2TField.setvisible(true);
}
else if (if.size = 3){
    id1.setvisible(true);
    weight1TField.setvisible(true);
    id2.setvisible(true);
    weight2TField.setvisible(true);
    id3.setvisible(true);
    weight3TField.setvisible(true);
}
```

So on... untill ID8.

The values are added to the array from a jtable in another Jframe when user has selected the rows(maximum 8 rows).

```
List<String> ID = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to create text fields to allow the user to input their weights and jlabels showing the ID beside the textfield e.g ID: TextField. Image is shown below
[image]

ID[i] is replaced with the value in the array if there is one while the rest is hidden if there is no value. How can i create the Jlabels and JTexFields without doing the following below.

```
ID1.setText(ID[0]);
ID2.setText(ID[1]);
ID3.setText(ID[2]);
ID4.setText(ID[3]);
ID5.setText(ID[4]);
ID6.setText(ID[5]);
ID7.setText(ID[6]);
ID8.setText(ID[7]);
```

Comment: Did you try `setVisible(false)`?

Comment: yes i did, but the array is not always filled with 8 IDs which means i will have to write multiple ifs statements for each individual case that is why i wanted to see if anyone has a way with not doing that step

Comment: Without seeing more code it's hard to tell but if your list (I'd use that and not an array) contains only the fields and labels that should be visible then where's the problem? You'd probably recreate the panel or at least the layout whenever you update the list to reflect changes in the row selection anyways.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) (Make the MCVE / SSCCE have just 2 or 3, **not** all 8) 3) It seems (from the limited information provided) that this GUI (& the end user) might better be served by having a single text field / label and a list (`JList`) beside them to allow the user to display / edit the information in the label / field.

Answer (score 0):

What about instead of using fields (I am not sure you are using fields, but the only thing i can do without more code is guess) to store the components into arrays? I have done an example with JLabels, you can do the same with textfields.

```
private static int idsCount = 6; //The number of ids. Let's say 6
private JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[8]; // Keep the array as a field. (8 = max capacity)

private void initIDLabels {
    for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        labels[i] = new JLabel();
        // add this font to all labels.
        labels[i].setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    }
    changeLabelsVisibility();
}

private void changeLabelsVisibility() {
    // Hide all labels.
    for (JLabel label : labels) {
        label.setVisible(false);
    }
    // Show all labels that supposed to be visible
    for (int i = 0; i < idsCount; i++) {
        labels[i].setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using your code but it does not seem to be displaying anything when I set a value in them nothing is showing.

Comment: @MineFlamerKaiBin You have to give us more code in order to give you more help.